# Python error in list: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, excel, list

I have made this code, which I would like to use to create an excel file containing in one sheet of metrics and in the second sheet a part only of those metrics. The condition for entering the second sheet is that there must already be a metric in the first list, so the second list is a list of duplicate objects.

```
res = []
res2 = []
seen = set()
def add_entry(res, id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5):
    # add to seen set
    seen.add(tuple([id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]))
    # append to results list
    res.append({'Display ID': id, 'title': t1, 'affectedEntities': t2, 'impactedEntities': t3, 'startTime': t4, 'endTime': t5})
    return res

def doppie(res2, id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5):
    if (id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5) in seen:
        res2.append({'Display ID': id, 'title': t1, 'affectedEntities': t2, 'impactedEntities': t3, 'startTime': t4, 'endTime': t5})
        return res2


args = [m, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]
res = add_entry(res, *args)
res2 = doppie(res2, m, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("tabella.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
CreateExcel2(res, writer, "sheet 1")
CreateExcel2(res2, writer, "sheet 2")
writer.close()#chiusura del file excel
```

Running this code however I get as error:

```
res = add_entry(res, *args)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
seen.add(tuple([id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I solve it? or do it in a better way?

I tried this as well and it gives me the same error

```
def add_entry(res, id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5):
    # add to seen set
    if (id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5) not in seen:
        seen.add(tuple([id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]))
    # append to results list
    res.append({'Display ID': id, 'title': t1, 'affectedEntities': t2, 'impactedEntities': t3, 'startTime': t4, 'endTime': t5})
    return res
```

Comment: Have you tried:

args = [res, m, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]


res = add_entry(*args)

Comment: res is the list where args then goes into it